# Setting the value of primary Key manually on Entity Model before insert

Tags: entity-framework

I have my Entity model where every entity has a primary key and they are marked with StoreGeneratedPattern = "Identity", the entity I am interested in is PEOPLE. It was created in oracle, and in another schema exists a "PEOLPE_HIST" table with it sequence. Before insert into PEOPLE I search on PEOPLE_HIST and if the person exists. I get the history information to including the ID (primary key) to insert into new PEOPLE table. I created a trigger for PEOPLE table to check if the ID is greater than or equal to 0, if it is, then I will not use the sequence and insert the Hist ID.

Is this possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you checking that the person exists?

Comment: The name of the person and birthdate (and many info) is captured in tha MVC form, i search the person in the history table, if it's found  i replace the info captured with the history info in PEOPLE object including de PK ID, after this i execute MyContext.SaveChanges

Comment: If have id with store generated pattern set to identity you can't set its value in application - it must be set in the database. If you want to set it in the application you set store generated pattern to none.